# how to add modifier passed as parameter to the end of Modifier?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a function:

```
@Composable
fun sendNewSmsText(passedModifier: Modifier){
Text(text = stringResource(R.string.when_sms_not_received),
    style = Typography.body2.copy(),
    modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)
 )
}
```

how to add a passedModifier to the text's end?
like:

```
@Composable
 fun sendNewSmsText(modifier: Modifier){
  Text(text = stringResource(R.string.when_sms_not_received),
    style = Typography.body2.copy(),
    modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp).passedModifier
  )
 }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `Modifier.then()`

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#then(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier)

Modifier.padding(4.dp).then(passedModifier)

Comment: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/docs/compose-api-guidelines.md#do-8

To my understanding, official guidelines discourage developers from concatenating internal modifiers to the beginning of the passed ones.
"Element functions MUST NOT concatenate additional modifiers to the beginning of the received modifier parameter before passing the concatenated modifier chain to the Compose UI node they emit."