# Is .then() syntax a strict requirement when concatenating Compose modifiers?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to know whether this is necessary to use .then() when combining Compose modifiers.
Let's consider a simple example.

```
@Composable
fun TestComposable(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
   // content 1 or 2
}
```

1. Row(modifier = modifier.then(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(10.dp))
2. Row(modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(10.dp)

As I understand it, the only drawback of doing it the "2" way, is that we can only concatenate internal modifiers to the passed ones, not the other way around. Am I missing something?

Comment: `.then()` allows you to create conditional modifiers. With it you can do something like `Modifier.then(if(condition) Modifier.fillMaxSize() else Modifier)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example above it's not strictly required.

As @Rafsanjani mentioned in comments it lets you create conditional modifiers.

Or change order of modifiers in situations when you don't want modifier from user to be in first order since order of Modifiers matter for padding,  drawing behind or front, or borders, size modifiers use initial one if not forced with Modifier.required.

And order of touch modifiers with padding or graphicsLayer determines clickable area bounds or shape. Modifier.then gives opportunity to customize order and give chance to create conditional modifiers.

### Edit

You can use it to swap order of Modifiers but you shouldn't do it with modifiers that are exposed in public Composable functions. However this is an approach you can use if you know internally.

```
Modifier.myModifier().then(modifier)
```

Comment: Note that official API guidelines for Jetpack Compose explicitly forbids adding modifiers to the beginning of the received modifier, so the example you provide is not the best one. https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/docs/compose-api-guidelines.md#elements-accept-and-respect-a-modifier-parameter

Comment: It doesn't **forbid** it. It says you must not use it. If it was forbidden it might have crashed or not allow you to use it. If you search Modifier questions in stackoverflow you will see that it has been used as `Modifier.someModifier.then(modifier)` and when you build your custom Layouts its an approach you use often. I agree to point it should not be done in most cases especially when it interacts with Modifiers from public function, i stand corrected there but it requires and in some circumstances to swap order of modifiers for internal Composable functions.

Comment: Thank you guys, the part about the ordering is what I tried to express in the question in the last paragraph. So from what I understand from your comments so far, the only benefit is being able to apply conditional modifiers this way. Another one I just thought of is reusing some of the already concatenated modifiers.

Comment: Swapping order of a Modifier helps under some circumstances like touch order or some padding based on your internal logic. However i agree it might not be best to do it with a modifier exposed to user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68054109/how-to-add-modifier-passed-as-parameter-to-the-end-of-modifier